# Functions and random integers

Tags: function, python-3.x, loops, random, integer

I want to first say this is my homework, so I do not want it done for me I just need some guidance as my teacher is not providing it for me nor can I find my answer online. Here is my problem

> Write a program that displays a table of distance equivalents in miles and kilometers. You must generate the table by running a function inside a loop in main. Generate a random integer from 10 to 60, inclusive, in each loop cycle. Use this latter value as the miles argument to the function. The function must then print a line in the table. Repeat: The function prints the table.

I am able to get the top part of the table to print correctly. When I run my code at the top it gives me the calculation for the kilometers but then just prints the same number 10 times.

How do I get it to print out the 10 random numbers for the miles and the calculations in the right spot for the kilometers?

#### Example output:

```
  MILES   KILOMETERS
52.00     83.68568
11.00     17.70274
40.00     64.37360
21.00     33.79614
14.00     22.53076
23.00     37.01482
48.00     77.24832
22.00     35.40548
15.00     24.14010
16.00     25.74944
```

obviously the sample output is supposed to be in two different columns for the miles and the kilometers but I couldn't figure out how to set that up on here.

my code

```
import random
  def main():
      print('Miles\tKilometers')
      miles = random.randint(10, 60)
      find_kilometers(miles)
      for number in range(10):
      print(miles)



 def find_kilometers(miles):
         kilometers = miles * 1.60934
         print(format(kilometers, '.5f'))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late for your homework, but I'll answer anyway.

You're assigning the value for `miles` outside of your for loop, so it's going to use that single value 10 times.

Also I'm assuming that it's just a typo in your post but the `print(miles)` line should be indented so it's within the for loop.